# Can I set the app.config 'useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy' attribute programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, configuration, app-config

I had to migrate a .NET 3.5 to 4.0 but some dll's were not loading, after googling I found that creating an app.config would solve it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

I would like to setup these options without using configuration files, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is technically possible.  You'd have to host the CLR yourself so you can call the [ICLRRuntimeInfo::BindAsLegacyV2Runtime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee426955.aspx) method before you create the primary AppDomain.  A .config file would normally be a much lower pain point unless you are already hosting.

Comment: You're right, I will stick with app.config, however I found what you said interesting, do you know where I could find information about writing a custom host for the CLR?

Comment: Steven Pratschner's book: http://www.amazon.com/Customizing-Microsoft-Framework-Language-Runtime/dp/0735619883/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1274990671&sr=1-3

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to set this at runtime, from within a .NET application or library, with some limitations.  You can use the `ICLRRuntimeInfo` interface to handle this.  For details, [see this article](http://reedcopsey.com/2011/09/15/setting-uselegacyv2runtimeactivationpolicy-at-runtime/).

Comment: Hi Reed, I want to set the following programmatically:
<configuration>
    <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>  
    </startup>
</configuration>

How can I do this? Please help. I am stuck.

Comment: @TheKing you would have to host and load clr yourself for that